# Unhandled Rejection (TypeError): Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'setState')

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Why I am having this error? ***Unhandled Rejection (TypeError): Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'setState')***? is this because of this doesn't detect in the addDepartment
it can not understand that this is the CustomToolbar component? please help.

```
class CustomToolbar extends React.Component {
  //

  constructor(props) {
    super(props)
    this.HandleAdd = this.HandleAdd.bind(this);
    }
  HandleAdd = () => {
  Swal.fire({
    title: 'Add Department',
    text: "Input department name below.",
    showCancelButton: true,
    confirmButtonColor: '#3085d6',
    cancelButtonColor: '#d33',
    confirmButtonText: 'Save',
    html: generateInputForms({
      strname: '',
      intsequence: ''
    }),

    preConfirm: () => {
      let strname = document.getElementById('strname').value;
      let intsequence = document.getElementById('intsequence').value;
 
      if (!strname) {
        Swal.showValidationMessage('The Department field is required.')
      }
      if (!intsequence) {
        Swal.showValidationMessage('The Sequence field is required.')
      }
      return {
        strname: document.getElementById('strname').value,
        intsequence: document.getElementById('intsequence').value
      }
    }
  }).then((result) => {
    if (result.isConfirmed) {
      let request = {
        strresourcename: "Richard",
        strapplicationcode: "SchoolApp",
        strmodulename: "Department",
        strtablename: "fmDepartments",
        strfieldid: "fmDepartmentsId",
        strname:document.getElementById('strname').value,
        intsequence:document.getElementById('intsequence').value
      }
      addDepartment(request).then(function(res){
        if (res.status == 200){
          Swal.fire({
            icon: 'success',
            title: 'Department',
            text: 'New Department has been added successfully.',
          }).then((res) => this.setState(Department))
        }else{
          Swal.fire({
            icon: 'error',
            title: 'Oops',
            text: 'Something went wrong.',
          })
        }
      })
    }
  })
}
  render() {
    const { classes } = this.props;

    return (
      <React.Fragment>
        <Tooltip title={"Add"}>
            <Button
              variant="contained"
              color="primary"
              size="small"
              style={{
                textTransform: 'unset',
                outline: 'none',
                marginLeft: 20,
                backgroundColor: '#00B029',
              }}
              onClick={this.HandleAdd}
              className={classes.button}
              startIcon={<AddIcon className={classes.addIcon} style={{color: '#fff',}} />}
            >
              Add
            </Button>
        </Tooltip>
      </React.Fragment>
    );
  }

}
```

error image

[image]

> Please ignore this meesage because so I can post a question here,
> thanks.

Comment: @CherryDT what do you mean?

Comment: @CherryDT just like this ? `(res => this.setState(this.state))`?

Comment: i get the same error

Comment: `Unhandled Rejection (Error): setState(...): takes an object of state variables to update or a function which returns an object of state variables.`

Comment: Please don't repurpose a question. The old one should be solved (you can accept my answer if you wish) and a new one created. I'm reverting your edit. Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You currently use a regular function as the callback to `addDepartment(...).then` which will have its own `this` (in this case `undefined` because the caller doesn't bind anything). Use an arrow function instead which doesn't have its own `this`. Change `function (res)` to `res =>`:

```js
addDepartment(request).then(res => {
  // ...
})
```

For more details, see [Are 'Arrow Functions' and 'Functions' equivalent / interchangeable?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34361379/are-arrow-functions-and-functions-equivalent-interchangeable/34361380#34361380)